# Can't use the variable value in Docker Pull Command in Azure Devops Pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created a build pipeline where I need to pull the Images from private ACR repo.
The version to be pulled is stored in a file which I read using a regex expression and sed command of Linux

```
- bash :
    MONGO=$(sed -n -e '/Mongo_Service_Version/ s/.*\= *//p' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/.env | 
    sed 's/ *$//g')
    echo $MONGO
```

The above prints the correct version that is present in the .env file (Eg: 4.0)
But now when I use the same variable to pull the image from Private repo I get an error of `invalid reference`

```
- bash :
    MONGO=$(sed -n -e '/Mongo_Service_Version/ s/.*\= *//p' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/.env | 
    sed 's/ *$//g')
    echo $MONGO
    docker pull my.repo/mongo:$MONGO
```

An interesting point to note is that if I give a hardcoded value to the MONGO variable like 4.0 the above thing works. Also, echo command writes the correct output for the variable but I am not sure why I am not able to use it with docker pull command.

I tried docker pull command in different syntax as mentioned below, but I get the same error

```
docker pull klingelnberg.azurecr.io/gearengine/mongo:${MONGO}
docker pull "klingelnberg.azurecr.io/gearengine/mongo:$MONGO"
```

```
MONGO_VERSION=$(sed -n -e '/Mongo_Service_Version/ s/.*\= *//p' $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/deployment/.env | sed 's/ *$//g')
MONGO="my.repo/mongo:$MONGO_VERSION"
docker pull $MONGO
```

What I think is the variable value my be having some escape characters or something that does not get printed but used when pulling the image. (Maybe color code values or as such)
The above is just my guess.

Comment: Could you please add another command `echo ${MONGO} | cat -vte` after this `MONGO="my.repo/mongo:$MONGO_VERSION"` and share the output.